# Pass variable in Twig tag

Tags: templating, form, plugin-formbuilder2

My template has this line that I want to update from a field in craft:

```
{% set form = craft.formBuilder2.getFormByHandle('schoolTrip') %}
```

I want 'schoolTrip' to be replaceable by a plain text field in craft. My plain text field is named 'formName'.

```
{% set form = craft.formBuilder2.getFormByHandle('block.formName') %}
```

just gives me errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's giving you errors because you put the variable in quotes. Ditch the quotes and try it like this...

```
{% set form = craft.formBuilder2.getFormByHandle(entry.formName) %}
```

Comment: When I do that I get Internal Server Error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: What is `block`? I assumed that was a matrix block (or similar).

Comment: sorry, its just a good ole Plain Text field

Comment: Updated my example. Assuming you're on a normal entry page, change `block` to `entry`.